Geometry of destabilizing centers in $K$-stability
In $K$-stability destabilizing centers are, roughly speaking, centers of valuations computing the stability thresholds.
It is known that if $X$ is non $K$-semistable Fano variety then there exists a unique subvariety $Z\subset X$ such that $Z$ is a destabilizing center of $X$ and $Z$ is minimal in the sense that it is contained in any other destabilizing center of $X$.
Is there any general result on the birational geometry of $Z$? For instance, is $Z$ rationally connected?

You are right that $Z$ is rationally connected. You can see this by taking the divisorial $\delta$-minimizer $E$ centered at $Z$, and extract a divisor $F$ on $X\times\mathbb{A}^1$  centered at $Z\times 0$ such that $r(\mathrm{ord}_F) = \mathrm{ord}_E$, and run a MMP to get the destabilizing test configuration $\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{A}^1$. Then we know that $F$ is birational to $\mathcal{X}_0$ which is a klt Fano variety, hence rationally connected. This implies $Z$ is rationally connected as it is dominated by $F$.
I think by subadjunction one can further show that $Z$ is of Fano type (without assuming $\mathbb{Q}$-factoriality).
